# jQuery Ajax Submit Post not getting success message back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The code works on until I reach the action.php where I post my input. The issue is that the Post never reaches the action.php and all I get is a blank variable.

using: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitdata()
{
 var name=document.getElementById('name');

 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'action.php',
  data: {
   'name':name
  },
  cache:false,
  success: function (data) {
   $('#msg').html(data);
  }
 });

 return false;
}

</script>

<form onsubmit="return submitdata();">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>

<p id="msg"></p>
```

action.php:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
echo "Response: ".$name;
?>
```

EDIT:
Fixed it by adding:

var name=document.getElementById('name').value;

and

input type="text" id="name" instead of name="name"

Comment: please check this example link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "name" is DOM object. To get value use:

```
var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
```

You now submit not a string, but Object and this may be the reason why it fails.

Comment: you are right. also, I should have added ID in the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the dataType on your ajax request
make it 'text'

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'action.php',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: {
   'name':name
  },
  cache:false,
  success: function (data) {
   $('#msg').html(data);
  }
 });
```

Comment: dataType: 'text', you forgot the coma :)